# IS vertical align possible with ServerRelativeImageUrl?

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

I need to create News page with PowerShell. Is it possible to set vertical align of image set in Page properties?

```
#Set Page properties
Set-PnPClientSidePage -Identity $Page -Title "Nowe wydanie numer $number dla wersji: $whatApp" -CommentsEnabled:$False -HeaderType Custom -ServerRelativeImageUrl $imageUrl
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot set vertical align of image set in Page properties. Accroding to the article： https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/set-pnpclientsidepage?view=sharepoint-ps

The parameters for image are only -TranslateX and -TranslateY. There is no such parameters to set vertical align of image.